# Why does this view magically change size?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I got a tableView with a tableFooterView.

On viewDidload:

```
 <UIView: 0x6c87a70; frame = (0 325; 320 3); autoresize = TM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x6c87aa0>>
  <UIImageView: 0x6c87b60; frame = (31 0; 257 3); autoresize = W+H; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x6c87ba0>> - table_pull_refresh_footer.png
```

On viewWillLayoutSubviews what I see is

```
<UIView: 0x6c87a70; frame = (0 325; 320 3); autoresize = TM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x6c87aa0>>
 <UIImageView: 0x6c87b60; frame = (31 0; 320 3); autoresize = W+H; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x6c87ba0>> - table_pull_refresh_footer.png
```

So why the UIImageView suddenly becomes big? The parentView doesn't change size at all. It's still 320 3.

Comment: Does the view's bounds change?

Comment: does your `viewWillLayoutSubviews` call `[super viewWillLayoutSubviews]` before you log the views?

Comment: if you subclass a plain UIViewController you won't need to call it. but for other view controller it could be necessary.

Comment: Unless you're doing something funky, I can't reproduce the problem with the information given.  A little more code would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

The problem was exactly as vikingosgundo said.

I should have called [super viewWillLayoutSubviews] first